# angularjs initiating controller scope from a service

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to preserve scope data between route changes, so I created a service to return saved data to a controller for it to initiate on scope.

```
app.factory('answerService', function () {
    var answers = {
        1 : { text : "first answer" },
        2 : { text : "second answer" }
    }
    return {
        getAllAnswers: function () {
            return answers;
        },
        getFirstAnswer: function () {
            return answers[1];
        }
    }
});
```

In my controller, I initiate the first answer by calling the service to get the first answer.

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, answerService) {
    $scope.firstAnswer = answerService.getFirstAnswer();    
    $scope.answers = answerService.getAllAnswers();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hientc/gj5knrg7/2/

The problem I'm having is that $scope.firstAnswer is somehow  also being binded to $scope.answers. I don't want that, I only want the input to bind to scope.firstAnswer.text

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `answers[1]` is an object reference, and assigning its value to another variable signifies that the variable is a reference to that object. In order to get a copy of that value you can copy it using `angular.copy()`.

Simply change `getFirstAnswer()` function to something like this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/LxpL7pya/)

```
getFirstAnswer: function () {
  return angular.copy(answers[1]);
}
```